# ASP.NET 2.0 C# Application crashes with Memory Access Violation on NTDLL

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, asp.net-web-api2, mongodb-.net-driver, iis-8.5

We have a series of ASP.Net Web API 2.0 applications that run on a common server (Server 2012 with IIS 8.5).  Each application is in its own application pool. The stack is .NET 4.5, RabbitMQ driver 3.6.6 and MongoDB driver 1.11, postsharp express

Recently, the applications have begun crashing at random intervals with Access Violation exceptions.

Reviewing Crash Dumps gave no particularly useful information... at least not to me.  Here are the two (consistent) reasons for crashes:

```
In w3wp.exe.13880.dmp the assembly instruction at ntdll!RtlpxLookupFunctionTable+3b in C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll from Microsoft Corporation has caused an access violation exception (0xC0000005) when trying to write to memory location 0x06d00ff8 on thread 0

In w3wp.exe.1628.dmp the assembly instruction at ntdll!RtlAcquireSRWLockShared+b in C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll from Microsoft Corporation has caused an access violation exception (0xC0000005) when trying to write to memory location 0x611e0ff8 on thread 0
```

Also, all dumps seem to start the stack trace for the crash (and several other threads) with:

```
kernel32!ExitProcessImplementation+a 
mscoreei!RuntimeDesc::ShutdownAllActiveRuntimes+27b 
msvcrt!_crtCorExitProcess+59 
msvcrt!_crtExitProcess+d 
msvcrt!doexit+15b 
w3wp!ParseCommandLine+bec 
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+22 
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+34
```

Any ideas how to debug this more effectively? I have tried different methods of memory dumps, logging, and debugging Managed memory from the dump... but no success so far.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case this helps anyone else... this particular issue was caused by a lack of thread safety on SuatinSoft PdfFocus which was using unmanaged code in the GDI to convert PDF pages to images.  When two threads accessed that code at the same time, it caused the memory access violation